# Any way to listen for the last api call to finish in React?

Tags: reactjs

So I am trying to set a loading screen. But I don’t know where to set the state for the loading screen to turn off. If I even put that function in componentwillupdate it stops showing the loading screen before all the data is fetched from the api calls. I put a timeout function to set the state after 4 seconds in componentdidmount after all the async functions, but I was told that was probably bad practice. Is there anyway I can listen for all the network api calls to be done? Like maybe wait 2 seconds after the last call changes from pending?

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. To make suggestions we need a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also, if all the API calls are async (as should be) why don't you set your loading state after all of them?

Answer (score 1):

The reasoning may be something like this:

1. Declare a state variable to indicate loading (eg. `isLoading`) and set it's initial value to `true`.
2. After data fetching is finished, set `isLoading` to `false`
3. In your `render` method, return `LoadingScreen` component if `isLoading` is `true`, otherwise actual component as follows.

```js
render(){
  return isLoading ? <LoadingScreen /> : <YourComponent />;
}
```

Comment: Right so that’s what I currently have but it looks as if the api call is fetched multiple times before everything is fully loaded. So the state is set to false way too soon and the loading screen shows way too early.

 Can’t pin point why.

Comment: Actually I couldn't get what you are trying to explain completely. Can you edit your question with new details in a comprehensive manner?